# Call child component method from parent component in reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have requirement to call child component method from parent component 
in reactjs. I have tried using refs but not able to do it. Can anyone please  suggest any solution.
Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Call child method from parent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949981/call-child-method-from-parent)

Comment: Although I'm very late to this, I'm also learning React so I'm curious about the case in which a parent would need to call child method. Would you care to explain?

Answer (score 8):

If using React Hooks, you can make use of useRef and useImperativeHandle hooks.

In the child component, add the functions in the hook.

```
const Child = forwardRef((props, ref) => {

  const printSomething = () =>{
     console.log('printing from child function')
  }
  useImperativeHandle(ref, () => ({
    printSomething: printSomething
  }));

  return <h1>Child Component</h1>;
});
```

Call the exposed function from the parent with the ref.

```
const Parent = () => {
  const childRef = useRef();

  return (
    <div>
      <Child ref={childRef} />
      <button onClick={() => childRef.current.printSomething()}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
};
```

Answer (score 3):

Don't :)

Hoist the function to the parent and pass data down as props. You can pass the same function down, in case the child needs to call it also.

https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/lifting-state-up.html

Comment: There are use cases when a parent component wants to trigger an action in a child component, like to trigger its focus. A state variable change on the parent could do that, but it is not practical. You would have to make a counter of something like that and it does not look like a good implementation. The React forwardRef hook specifically mentions this focus use case in its official docs here: https://react.dev/reference/react/forwardRef#usage

Answer (score 3):

You can assign a ref to the child component and then call the function form parent like

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
   callChildFunction = () => {
       this.child.handleActionParent();  ///calling a child function here
  } 
   render(){
      return (
           <div>
           {/* other things */}
           <Child ref={(cd) => this.child = cd}/>
           </div>
      )
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
   handleActionParent = () => {
       console.log('called from parent')
   }
   render() {
      return (
           {/*...*/}
      )
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can pass `registerCallback` props to your child and call it from componentDidMount and pass reference to your child component method, then you can call it method at anytime

Answer (score 1):

in your parent you can create a reference

in the constructor:

```
 this.child = React.createRef();
```

in any function:

```
execute=(comment)=>{
        this.child.current.addComment();
    }

render(){
        return (
            <div>
                <Messages ref={this.child} comment={this.state.comment}/>
            </div>
        )
    }
```

and in the Message(child) component

```
addComment=()=>{
    console.log("Pi ", this.props);

  };
```